# How to copy the values of an array of char pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How do I copy the values in an array of char pointers into another array? I am really lost please help me out. This is what I have so far.

```
char **copy_values(char **values) {
    char **val;

    //do something 
    return val;
}
```

Comment: You have to pass the size of the array to the function, as there is no way of telling the size from the pointer.

Comment: What have you thought about so far?

Comment: You also need to decide whether you're doing a deep copy or a shallow copy. And whether those `char` pointers point to strings, or simple arrays. In other words, you haven't really told us what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

To fully copy the *pointers* and values (*what they point to*), you need to know three things:

1. How many pointers do I have?
2. Do I need to also copy the things they point to?; and if so
3. How many pointers do I have that point to something I need to copy.

When you declare a *pointer to pointer to char*, it is simply an uninitialized pointer. To provide the ability to address more than a single address, you then allocate some needed number of pointers (say `MAXPTRS`). For instance:

```
#define MAXPTRS 32
...
char **values = NULL;

values = malloc (MAXPTRS * sizeof *values);   /* allocate MAXPTRS pointers */
if (values == NULL) {                         /* validate/handle error */
    perror ("malloc-values");
    /* handle error */
}
```

You now have `MAXPTRS` (`32`) pointers to work with. If you then allocate storage for say `8` of them, e.g.

```
size_t count = 0;
while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    size_t len = strlen (buf);
    values[count] = malloc (len + 1);
    if (!values[count]) {
        perror ("malloc-values[count]");
        break;
    }
    memcpy (values[count++], buf, len + 1);
}
```

So at this point in the example, you have `32` pointers allocated and `8` of those pointers pointing to blocks of memory holding strings read from `stdin`.

If you then want to copy the entire structure, you must not only copy the original `32` pointers, but also the `8` blocks of memory the initialized pointers point to. If you fail to copy the blocks of memory pointed to and simply assign pointers (e.g. `val[i] = values[i]`), then any changes to the original, e.g. `values[2]` will automatically be reflected in `val[2]` (this may, or may not, be what you want)

To fully copy your `values` pointer to pointer to char and return `val` containing the same number of pointers with a copy of each string allocated and contained in the original `values` array of pointers, you would need a "deep copy" where you copy not only the pointers, but duplicate the contents as well, e.g.

```
char **copystrings (const char **values, size_t nptrs, size_t filled) 
{
    char **val = NULL;

    val = malloc (nptrs * sizeof *val);     /* allocate nptrs pointers */
    if (!val) {                             /* validate */
        perror ("malloc-val");
        return NULL;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < filled; i++) {   /* loop over each filled ptr */
        size_t len = strlen (values[i]);    /* get length of string */
        val[i] = malloc (len + 1)           /* allocate storare val[i] */
        if (!val[i]) {                      /* validate */
            perror ("malloc-val[i]");
            break;
        }
        memcpy (val[i], values[i], len + 1);    /* copy to val[i] */
    }

    return val;     /* return val (may contain less than filled allocated) */
}
```

(**note:** not compiled, also it would be advisable to pass `filled` as a pointer and update `filled` with the value of `i` before returning to provide a means of validating that all blocks of memory for `filled` pointers were duplicated. Otherwise, a `malloc` failure of `val[i]` would result in less than `filled` being allocated and copied and no way to tell -- unless you used `calloc` to zero the new memory when you allocate for `val`)

A deep copy allows you to modify the copied values without altering the data at the addresses pointed to by the pointers in `values`. If you are not modifying the data (e.g. you simply want to sort the pointers with `qsort`, then there is no need for a "deep copy" and you need only allocate for the `filled` number of pointers and assign the address from `values` to `val`.

Understanding what you need and the differences in how you go about achieving it is key.

(thanks to [@4386427](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4386427/4386427) for catching a couple of omissions)

Comment: Nice detailed answer. Some nitpicks: 1) `if (!values[count]) {` seem to be missing a `}`. b) The mentioning of reading 8 strings is a bit confusing as the loop doesn't terminate by itself after 8 strings. And … if only 8 pointers are initialized the deep-copy will be UB. Maybe `while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {` ==> `while (count < 32 && fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {`

Comment: Yep, you are correct. This is one I just wrote and didn't compile. Will tweak. The use of `8` was more of a "what if we had 8-filled" more than anything else. I intended that `8` would be passed as `filled` to `copystring` for the example.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I copy the values in an array of char pointers into another array?

Something like:

```
char **copy_values(char **values, int size) {
    char **val = malloc(size * sizeof *val);
    if (val) memcpy(val, values, size * sizeof *val);
    return val;
}
```

Remember to `free` the allocated memory when done with it

Comment: Well, that will only copy the "*pointers*". If they pointers point to anything, you need a separate copy of each block of memory (a "deep copy").

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Exactly. And that's OP is asking. Copying the pointed to object as well is another story.

Comment: It's not clear, but I read it as *"How do I copy the* **values** *in an array of char pointers..."*.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The **values** in an array of integers are integers. The **values** in an array of pointers are pointers. Maybe OP wants something differently but as the question is, OP asked for a copy of the pointer values.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin And... Even if OP really want copies of the **pointed to objects** there is no way to help as we can't tell what the pointers point to. Is it strings (so we can use `strlen`), is it single chars, is it a fixed number of chars, ...